# What's the correct way to use methods from a sibling widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to clean my code by putting different widgets in different files/classes so it's not all inside the same main widget.

So right now I have this:

```dart
MainWidget {
Scaffold {
    body: MyWebView(),
    bottomNavigationBar: MyNavBar(),
}
}
```

Both are stateful widgets.

So now I'm wondering: how can I use methods from `MyWebView` from inside `MyNavBar`?

I've tried `MyWebView.of(context).method()` and even do a middle method inside `MainWidget` to try and call the methods from the parent widget always, but it's always "null". I've seen people mentioning PrivateKeys but many say this is an old way of doing things and I shouldn't rely on that.

So how can I do this?

Comment: you can lift up the state, and keep the function in your parent widget, or you can pass a global key to the widget you need the function from, and use that key in other widgets to access the state class of that widget

Comment: @AliBakhtiyari What do you mean by lifting up the state?

And the GlobalKey I'd have to do it on the `MainWidget`, pass it onto the `MyWebView(key: key)` and then pass it to `MyNavBar(webviewKey: key)` to use it there?

Comment: try like this `final GlobalKey<WebViewState> wvKey = GlobalKey<WebViewState>();` . or instead of passing the state, you can pass variable. use `typedef`

Answer (score 1):

I would need more details to provide an exact solution but based on your question this is the answer:
You have two options to do what you need

1. **Lift Up The state**:
   This means In some situations, there are some states that are needed and shared among two or more sibling widgets, what we can do about it is to move those states to the parent widget, and provide it to the children, either by passing the variables and functions or using inherited-widget-based methods like using provider framework. so in your case, you can keep the function and state in the main widget, and pass it to both children.
2. Use a **Key** to access the MyWebView widget's state: as you mentioned in the comments, this is exactly done as you said :

> you'd have to do it on the MainWidget, pass it onto the MyWebView(key: key), and then pass it to MyNavBar(webviewKey: key) to use it there

Comment: Your point 2 is what I've been trying, the problem is that whenever I try to create the key, Android Studio complains about the state:
`final GlobalKey<WebViewState> wvKey = GlobalKey();` has a red line under `WebViewState` saying it's not a type. I imagine that's because this state is in another file so it can't be referenced, but I thought importing it would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass variable instead use `typedef`,

first declare outside `MyWebview` class :
let me guess, you need some int value from webview to pass it into `navbar` class.

```
typedef OndataProcessed = void Function(int valueIneed);
class MyWebView {
--------
final OndataProcessed ondataprocess;
```

and in `methods` in my webview

```
int someMethod (){

int result = blabla;

ondataprocess(result);
}
```

and finally :

```
MainWidget {
int resultfromwebview;
Scaffold {
    body: MyWebView(ondataprocess: (int result){
setstate((){resultfromwebview = result})
}),
    bottomNavigationBar: MyNavBar(index: result),
}
}
```

Comment: Not really, in my case I have to change URL with the WebView Controller. I imagine I could specify it on the MainWidget and do what you say, but I thought there could be a more reliable way to do it rather than have `MainWidget` have all the shared variables there

Comment: @Stasky you are seeking a state management solution rather than a stateful widget.
maybe this doc would help you : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options